# public onCreate(), or protected onCreate()?

Tags: android, public, protected, oncreate

While reading the "Hello, Android" book, I noticed that:

> each java file with `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` method, has
>   **protected** access modifier EXCEPT in the main Activity of the program [that has: `public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`].

Why is the `onCreate` method `public` on the program's main Activity, but `protected` everywhere else?

Comment: you can use **public** access modifier in all activity....

Comment: Can you tell us what did that program do?

Comment: It is a sudoku program, and as said before, all classes which has onCreate method -except in main activity- have 'protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)'. WHY?? i CAN'T believe there not be special reason!!

Answer (score 1):

You can change the visibility of a method. What you cannot do is : reduce the visibility (make a public method private), access a private method (making it public)

Answer (score 0):

It can as well be `protected`. There is nothing important or wise about that.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to make the method public (but doing so doesn't affect anything). You shouldn't call it manually anyway.

By the way Intellij IDEA have Activity template with public `onCreate`. This may be the reason this method public in the book.